# How do I add Yoxos Eclipse profile to the Windows 7 Taskbar?

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, taskbar

I have used Yoxos before and have managed to (almost) get it working how I wanted. I understand that it's designed so you launch a profile from the .yoxos file which is created when the profile is saved.
I found a hack that allows you to add a file to the taskbar, which works fine, however when I launch from the .yoxos file and Eclipse runs, and is a separate item in the taskbar.
How can I make it so when the file is launched, the Eclipse application is part of that item on the taskbar?
If I pin Eclipse to the taskbar and launch it, all the Yoxos customization components fail to load.

Anyone got any ideas?